# Matlab regexp after last match, to the end of the string

Tags: regex, matlab

I'm trying to match everything after the last match of a character (everything after the last "\".  This code works, but I'm wondering if I can do it with a single regexp command.

```
filename = 'c:\apps\testing\local\blah.txt';
chunks = strread(filename,'%s','delimiter','\\');
fname = chunks{end};
```

Comment: If you are working on file names try using fileparts function.

Comment: Yes, just use [`fileparts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html).

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to solve this:

```
[pathName, fileName, extension] = fileparts(filename);
```

With regex ("after backslash, take all characters that are not a backslash `([^\\]*)` until the end `$`, returning just those characters `'tokens'` and don't try to do multiple matches `'once'`")

```
extension = regexp(filename,'\\([^\\]*)$','tokens','once')
```